# CloverETL DBOutputTable - Update Statement Won't Complete

Tags: sql, sql-update, cloveretl

I'm running a process that updates flags in a SQL Server database table. Essentially, the graph reads a .csv file, then uses the variables in the update statement. The universal reader is completing but the DBOutputTable component is hanging and won't complete. The funny thing is that earlier in the graph there's another DBOutputTable component that does almost the exact same thing and finishes successfully. Does anyone know what the issue could be?

I've restarted the services and the server itself. This process typically completes without issue but it just started hanging a few days ago.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess non existing or not sufficient index on that table. That would manifest after a while, with larger data set.

Double check that previous DBOutputTable is doing update on same fields.